# Recover from JavaScript Disabling - Stuck on Alt <noscript> Page

Tags: javascript, page-refresh, noscript

I'm using `<noscript>` to show, in some cases, alternate content and, in other cases, alternate pages when JavaScript is disabled.

`<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=index-alt.php"></noscript>`

I'm using the Firefox plugin to enable/disable JavaScript for testing, but the effect is the same when using the Edit > Preferences option in Linux FF.

Basically, when JS is re-enabled, the alternate page (eg, `index-alt.php`) remains, and I'm stuck on that page.  I guess I really didn't consider this all that much after I implemented it and that was a mistake.

Is there a enable/disable JavaScript event I can bind to refresh my page to the default?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? It looks like you've moved to a different page; have you tried using the back-button?

Comment: Do people switch Javascript on and off and expect sites to respond to that?

Comment: @LeeTaylor The answer most certainly is no

Comment: @thatidiotguy Exactly. Ergo, I'd really not worry about it.

Comment: I know the situation is fringe but I want the site to function as cleanly as possible and the proposed answer certainly helps, despite what the user expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have re-enabled JavaScript, you would need to return to the original page to test the page with script enabled.

If you are worried about this happening "in real life", you could have a script tag on the no-script page that redirects to the script page, which would do the inverse of your noscript tag:

```
document.location.href = "/index.php";
```